# Which of the following sets of vectors are linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Which of the following set of vectors are linearly independent?
>
> [image]

I'm a bit confused. I think the answer(s) would be **A, C,** and **D**. I'm unsure of how to actually figure out if each one is or isn't LI/LD

Comment: do you in general know, how to do it or do you need hints how to find out on your own next time?

Comment: I need to know how to find it on my own basically

Comment: i will edit it in the answer. (might take a while since i must watch for my child menawhile) also see the other answers since up to now they are more detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c and d only. a is twice the same vector and thus the second vector is in the linear span of the first.

Answer (score 2):

If $v_1,v_2\cdots v_n$ are the vectors, then they will be independent if a linear combination of them turns out to be $0$ i.e. $\sum_i \alpha_i v_i=0$ for some $\{\alpha\}_i$(at least 1 $\alpha_i\ne0$).Now you see,

A) $v_1+(-1)v_2=0$ So DEPENDENT

B) 3 vectors, each have 1 common coordinate. So they must be dependent .(solve for yourself).

C) Independent . Satisfies definition of independence.

D) Only 1 vector. SO no question of independence

E)Dependent similar reason as (B)

F)Dependent $3\times v_1+0\times v_2=0$

Comment: @Shammy Can you please what else I have to add so as to make my answer **more acceptable** than the one you accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Vectors are linearly dependent in i can express one vector as linear combination of the others. To check this you have to solve a system. In case you have 2 vectors v = (v1,v2,v3) and w = (w1,w2,w3) you have to check if a(v1,v2,v3) + b(w1,w2,w3) = (0,0,0) where a ann b are parameters to calculate. Then (a*v1 + b*w1, a*v2 + b*w2, a*w3 + b*w3) = (0,0,0). So solve the system: a*v1 + b*w1 = 0; a*v2 + b*w2 = 0; a*v3 + b*w3 = 0. If a anb b exists, vectors are linearly dipendent. If not, are linearly indipendent. In your example vectors in A are linearly dependent because the two vectors are the same.